# Can Cypress retain browser information/data and not start a new session?

Tags: cypress

I'm running a test where it should be beneficial if Cypress didn't renew the browser session/remove cache/cookies, etc, so it essentially retained all the information i've inputted previously.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the `cy.session()` [command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Syntax), which is like a cache for cookies, localstorage, and session.

The only downside as far as I can see is you need to do all the setting (requests, etc) inside the `cy.session()` setup callback.

For example

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('init', () => {
    // request and set cookies
  })
})

it('first test', () => {
  // the beforeEach() for 1st test will fire the request
  ...
})

it('second test', () => {
  // the beforeEach() for 2nd test will set same values as before from cache
  // and not resend the request 
})
```

Note there's an flag that needs to be set in config

```js
experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a community plugin called [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session), where you need to set `shareAcrossSpecs` to `true` e.g.

```js
cy.dataSession({
  name: 'shared value',
  setup: () => 'a',
  validate: (x) => x === 'a',
  shareAcrossSpecs: true,
})
```

i.e.

> *If you want the data value to persist across the browser reloads, or be shared across specs*

More here: https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session#shareacrossspecs